# Peculiar "Vendor ID payload" messages in firewall log - what does it mean?

Tags: firewall, logging

I checked our firewall logs today and found thousands of these messages:

```
Jul  3 15:59:36 sg580 Pluto[295]: packet from 218.185.86.50:500: initial Main Mode message received on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:500 but no connection has been authorized
Jul  3 15:59:44 sg580 Pluto[295]: packet from 218.185.86.50:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02_n]
Jul  3 15:59:44 sg580 Pluto[295]: packet from 218.185.86.50:500: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03]
Jul  3 15:59:44 sg580 Pluto[295]: packet from 218.185.86.50:500: ignoring Vendor ID payload [4048b7d56ebce885...]
```

Can anyone help me decipher this?

I've added policy routes to drop packets to/from 218.185.86.50 - but I'm still getting these blooming log messages.

Too much for me poor ol' noggin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host at 218.185.86.50 is trying to set up an IPSEC VPN to you. Port 500 is the ISAKMP key exchange port.

JR

Answer (score 1):

In addition to JR's correct answer.

`Pluto[295]` indicates respectively the name of the daemon and PID that has logged the message. Pluto is the IKE (IPsec Key Exchange) portion of the [Open|Free]Swan VPN project.

If you're not expecting a VPN to be terminating on that machine or you are only expecting VPN sessions from particular hosts then you should take a look at locking it down.